# SQLObject throws: Unknown database 'dbname?charset=utf8'

Tags: python, mysql, sqlobject

I've got third-party Python script, it looks like it has to connect to MySQL database by means of `SQLObject` package.

Considering I've provided correct DSN, the script throws

> sqlobject.dberrors.OperationalError: Unknown database
>   'dbname?charset=utf8'

I've traced the problem to this piece of code

```
ar['charset'] = 'utf8'
conn = connectionForURI(uri, **ar)
```

which calls [this function](http://www.sqlobject.org/sqlobject/dbconnection.py.html?f=997&l=1020#997).

And it connects fine when `ar['charset'] = 'utf8'` is commented, so no query string is provided.

I have this issue on Windows,

- MySQL 5.5.25
- Python 2.7.2
- MySQL-python 1.2.5
- SQLObject 3.0.0a1dev-20150327

What exactly is going on there, and how it is supposed to be fixed? Does the problem lie in dependencies or the script itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some research and found out that recent version of SQLObject uses [the following code](http://www.sqlobject.org/sqlobject/dbconnection.py.html?f=191&l=227#191) to extract connection parameters from URI. Unfortunately, `urlparse` function works that way so `path` that is used as DB name further parsed with a query string.

As a workaround for this issue, I could suggest passing DB encoding parameter explicitly to the connection object as follow:

```
conn = connectionForURI(uri)
conn.dbEncoding = 'utf-8'
```

It might help but it's worth to make a pull request to fix DB name extraction from URI.

UPD: Older version like 2.x uses a different code to parse connection URL which works well.

Comment: Is that because SQLObject 3.x was installed instead of 2.x?

Comment: I don't quite good in versioning of SQLObject but I don't think that this behaviour differs from 2.x. Anyway, you may try to check it using `git history`.

Also, I found another function that parses URI and was written without `urlparse`. To use it you should call `connectionForURI` function with parameter `oldUri=False`

Comment: @estus My fault. Version 2.2 has different code to parse URI. Checking it. And it's work perfectly. Maybe you should use stable version.

Comment: Thank you for the research. Yes, 2.x works fine indeed, the one shouldn't rely on unconstrained package versions.

Answer (score 1):

Comma, not question mark:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PASS,
      db=DB_NAME, charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
```

If you can't get past the 3rd party software, abandon it.

Comment: I can't demand the support from the author of the script, I can't abandon it as well. I believe this problem relates to the one of the listed components and the question is quite specific on that.